# Многопоточный доступ к коллекции Java

Tags: java, многопоточность, concurrency, lock

Начал изучать многопоточность в Java и возник следующий вопрос: У меня есть некая коллекция, допустим map, которая содержит объекты Account c полем flot money = 100; Я хочу запустить 4 потока, которые будут переводить money c одного рандомного Acc на другой рандомный Acc. Я так понимаю когда я выберу рандомно два Acc следующие операции нужно обернуть в synchronized или lock(list содержит все ключи map, он Collections.synchronizedList,
round() - моя функция округления до двух знаков):

```
lock.writeLock().lock();
try {
    String idFrom = StartInit.listRandom.get(rnd.nextInt(StartInit.listRandom.size()));
    String idTo = StartInit.listRandom.get(rnd.nextInt(StartInit.listRandom.size()));
    float moneyTransfer = round(rnd.nextFloat() * Math.min(getAccountMoney(idFrom), getAccountMoney(idTo)), MAX_MONEY_SCALE);
    setAccountMoney(idFrom, getAccountMoney(idFrom) - moneyTransfer);
    setAccountMoney(idTo, getAccountMoney(idTo) + moneyTransfer);
} finally {
    lock.writeLock().unlock();
}
```

Но тогда получается смысл многопоточности теряется, так как доступ будет к map с Acc-ми предоставляться последовательно. Возможно есть более красивые и более действенные методы сделать это многопоточно?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev , как я понял, данный интерфейс не гарантирует, что два счета, с которого я снимаю и на который я зачисляю, не буду изменены в других потоках, в момент  float moneyTransfer = round(rnd.nextFloat() * Math.min(getAccountMoney(idFrom), getAccountMoney(idTo)), MAX_MONEY_SCALE); к примеру.

Answer (score 0):

Надо лочить конкретные эккаунты, а не иметь один общий лок. Т.е. в каждом эккаунте должен быть свой лок, который надо захватить. Так как надо захватить 2 аккаунта (как минимум) - то захват локов надо проводить строго попорядку- например по номеру счета (сначала с меньшим номером - потом с большим). Иначе получите дедлок. Скорость увеличится за счет того, что если в двух транзакциях разные счета, то операции пройдут независимо друг от друга.